# CPT Columns doesn't show categories

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, columns

I have the following code creating some Columns and reordering them to my CPT.

```
// SHOW THE FEATURED IMAGE
function pessoas_custom_columns_data($column_name, $post_ID) {
    if ($column_name == 'featured_image') {
        $post_featured_image = cpt_pessoas_featured_image($post_ID);
        if ($post_featured_image) {
            echo '<img class="bg_fi_postlist" src="' . $post_featured_image . '" />';

        }
    }
}

function reorder_pessoas_columns( $columnspessoas ) {
    $columnspessoas = array(
        'cb'                    => $columnspessoas['cb'],
        'featured_image'        => __( 'Pessoas' ),
        'title'                 => __( 'Nome' ),  // Post Title
        'categorias_de_pessoas' => __( 'Categorias' ),  // Categories for my CPT
        'post_type'             => __( 'Tipo' ),
        'author'                => __( 'Autor' ),
        'date'                  => __( 'Date' ) // Published Date
    );
    return $columnspessoas;
}

add_action( 'manage_pessoas_posts_custom_column' , 'pessoas_custom_columns_data', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'manage_pessoas_posts_columns', 'reorder_pessoas_columns' );
```

My question is:
why `'categorias_de_pessoas'  => __( 'Categorias' ),` doesn't the show the content within the categories selected to my post? This is a taxonomy called 'categorias_de_pessoas'.

Thank you once again.
AMP.

Comment: Does that column show when you don't use the filter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> why `'categorias_de_pessoas' => __( 'Categorias' ),` doesn't the show the content within the categories selected to my post? This is a taxonomy called 'categorias_de_pessoas'.

That issue happened because you did not prepend the taxonomy (or array key or column name) with a `taxonomy-`. I.e. The correct format is: `taxonomy-<taxonomy>`. See [`WP_Posts_List_Table::column_default()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_posts_list_table/column_default/).

So to fix the issue, use this instead: `'taxonomy-categorias_de_pessoas' => __( 'Categorias' ),`

And just wondering, why do you have a `post_type` column there?..

Comment: Thank you for your help. The solution was adding taxonomy- before my category name just like you said: 'taxonomy-categorias_de_pessoas'